# How to ignore webhook in push in my session?

Tags: git, jenkins, github

Inside my deploy stage in Jenkins (I run sh file) and I did some changes in the repo files during the deploy process. and I want to commit those files and push them into the master.

the problem is those actions will trigger another deploy/build stage in Jenkins. (since for every push- github send webhook to trigger the Jenkins)

How I push without trigger the webhook for the deploy session? maybe something like this? (`git push --without-trigger-webhook`)

I search a lot of how to do it right, in YouTube, Pluralsight docs on the web, but I don't find any good guide or solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

May be this approach can help.

You can create a webhook for **Branch or tag creation** shown below in the screenshot
[image]

So, whenever you want to run you build in jenkins for specific commit just try to commit and tag that commit. Thus, whenever you commit and add new tag to that commit, webhook will be triggered which will automatically build your Jenkins job for that tag.

You can refer this [blog](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/inspecting-a-repository/git-tag) for creating tag.

This way you can reduce the number of builds whenever you commit and push.